# Best way to save authentication token?

Tags: c#, security, token

I've been working on implementing an api in c#. The implementation is going well, but I did come across a concern.

When my library has authorized against the api I have a auth_token which I use for consequent queries to the webservice.

The token needs to be kept between program runs as it stays the same for the user (although I do check if it is still valid when the application starts).

For testing purposes I basically just save the token into a text file which is kept in the root directory of the app.

This works fine, but is this the best way?

Not sure the user will appreciate that it gets saved in a cleartext file (even if it is on his own pc).

So, what is general practice for saving tokens like this?

Comment: Encrypt the value, and then save it to the User Configuration file, I would then also encrypt the entire configuration file so it would be unique to the machine itself.  Please do not store this type of information in plain text you are right to question if thats a "good idea" because its not.

Comment: Paragraphs are your friend. Use them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use the [Windows Data Protection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms995355.aspx) There are numerous [examples](http://www.obviex.com/samples/dpapi.aspx) around on how to use it from C#.  It uses a user specific key to encrypt the data.  Only the user themselves can decrypt it.  Also be sure to secure the data during transmission between the server and the client.

Comment: The Windows Data Protection API can be used even if you save the information in the configuration file, database, registry, etc.

Comment: The examples link seems dead. Maybe update it if there's a typo, or to other reference?

Answer (score 0):

Create a settings file for your project in the project properties, add a `AuthToken` property to the known settings (probably at the user level), then use:

```
Properties.Settings.Default.AuthToken = userAuthToken;
```

If you think they'll want it hidden, encrypt or encode the `userAuthToken` so it is less obvious.

Answer (score 0):

You can verify if the api is used under asp.net or windows environment ( it's enough to check if Request is null) and on the first case use a cookie, on the latter save it on a registry key.

Answer (score 0):

That may work in a local app or running the CI locally, but if you are in DevOps (Azure) your test app will reside in your VM bin folder. After every deployment your bin folder gets wiped out so the token you saved in your bin files is gone. Perhaps the best way to save it will be encrypted in one of your DevOps environment variables in your release pipeline so you don't loose it.  When running locally you can save it anywhere.